# How to fix the error when passing JSON via Socket using Postman

Tags: java, json, sockets

My team is trying to build the application that detects the movement of the object and sending those information(JSON) to server(backend using java). I have tried to get JSON data via socket, but it shows this kind of error. I'm using postman to send JSON to test. Another question is using tomcat to get and post data from browser is better than using socket in this scenario?

```
public class ThreadedEchoServer {

    static final int PORT = 5000;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Client connect...");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("I/O error: " + e);
            }
            // new thread for a client
            new EchoThread(socket).start();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class EchoThread extends Thread {

    protected Socket socket;

    public EchoThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.socket = clientSocket;
    }

    public void run() {
        InputStream inp = null;
        BufferedReader brinp = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        try {
            inp = socket.getInputStream();
            brinp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inp));
//            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return;
        }
        String line;

        while (true) {
            try {
                line = brinp.readLine();
                if ((line == null) || line.equalsIgnoreCase("QUIT")) {
                    socket.close();
                    return;
                } else {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(line);
                    System.out.println("Client: " + json.toString());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is json that I used Postman to post request

```
{
    "id": 963,
    "result": "United States",
    "cook": 30
}
```

But I got this error

```
Client connect...
Exception in thread "Thread-0" org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:505)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:215)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:399)
    at EchoThread.run(EchoThread.java:34)
```

Comment: You have shown us some socket code, yet you say you are using Postman.  Which method are you actually using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hello Tim. I'm using POST request to send data.

Comment: @TriDo Postman is communicating using HTTP (which sits on top of TCP); your server code is expecting "raw" TCP. So, the Postman TCP stream will likely start with the verb and wherever you're posting to (assuming you are POSTing): "POST /some/endpoint/here HTTP/1.1". That won't deserialize into JSON.

Comment: @NotaJD Hi Nota, Can you give me any suggestion ?